# In IST, can nonstandard functions take standard objects to nonstandard objects?

Tags: logic, nonstandard-analysis

I'm asking specifically about a proof given in Edward Nelson's "Internal Set Theory: A New Approach to Nonstandard Analysis".

Here's the theorem statement:

If every finite subset of a graph admits a k-coloring, then the graph admits a k-coloring.

Here's Nelson's proof:

Wlog, let $G = (V, E)$ and $k$ be standard. Then, let $F\subset V$ be a finite subset containing all standard points in $V$. By hypothesis, $F$ has a $k$-coloring $f$. By (S) there is a standard function $g$ with domain $V$ such that $g$ agrees with $f$ on all standard inputs. By transfer, $g$ is a $k$-coloring for $G$.

Here's my question: how does standardization imply the existence of an extension $g$ of $f$ that has domain $V$?

My initial approach was to use standardization to construct the set $g$ generated by all standard elements of $f$, i.e. $g := \{(x,y)\in V \times k: (x, y)\in f \}$. However, while it's fairly straightforward to prove that $g$ is single-valued with domain included by $V$, I don't see how $dom(g) \supseteq V$.

In particular, I fail to see why it isn't possible for there to be some standard $x\in V$ such that $f(x)$ is not standard, allowing $(x, f(x))$ to not be contained in $g$. Is there some application of an axiom in IST that disallows this or otherwise lets us work around it?

Comment: In your title, did you mean "nonstandard functions" or "standard functions"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In particular, I fail to see why it isn't possible for there to be some standard x∈V such that f(x) is not standard,

There is no such element, because $f(x)$ belongs to the set $k$. And since $k$ is a standard finite set, all of its elements are standard. I'm sure you've already proved this fact at this point, but if not, you can refer to [Theorem 1.2.5](https://research.manchester.ac.uk/en/studentTheses/development-of-group-theory-in-the-language-of-internal-set-theor) in the introduction of my PhD thesis for a short and easy argument.

So in fact to all standard vertices of $G$, the function $f$ assigns a unique standard color. By Transfer, its standardization $g$ is then a function from the vertices of $G$ to $k$. This answers your question from the post.

---

Finiteness of the codomain $k$ is essential here. Pick a nonstandard natural $\omega \in \mathbb{N}$. The constant function $x \mapsto \omega$ then takes the standard number $0$ to the nonstandard $\omega$, which answers your titular question in the negative: in IST, nonstandard functions can take standard objects to nonstandard objects.

It's also not true that "if a function $f$ takes every standard value to some standard value, then $f$ is standard": for example, the map $x \mapsto H(x - \omega)$, where $H$ denotes the Heaviside step function, has this property, but is nonstandard.